# redux: Array.find() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks

i am working on a react native app, using basic redux for state management and complete beginner to this.in this specific problem im fetching data from my redux store in the edit screen where i also have a option to update the data

```
import React,{useState,useEffect,useCallback} from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { View,Text,StyleSheet,ScrollView,TextInput} from 'react-native';
import {Item, HeaderButtons} from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
import HeaderButton from '../../components/UI/HeaderButton';
import * as productActions from '../../store/actions/products';

const EditProductScreen= ({navigation}) => {

    const prodId= navigation.getParam('productId');
    const editedProduct= useSelector(state => state.product.userProducts.find(prod => prod.id === prodId));

    const dispatch= useDispatch();
   const [title,setTitle]=useState(editedProduct ? editedProduct.title : '');
   const [imageUrl,setImageUrl]=useState(editedProduct ? editedProduct.imageUrl : '')
   const [price,setPrice]=useState(editedProduct ? editedProduct.price : '');
   const [description,setDescription]=useState(editedProduct ? editedProduct.description : '');

const submitHandler = useCallback(() =>{

     if(editedProduct){
       navigation.navigate({routeName:'UserProducts'});
      dispatch(productActions.updateProduct(prodId,title,imageUrl,description));

      }else{
       dispatch(productActions.createProduct(title,imageUrl,description, +price));
     }
   },[dispatch,prodId,title,imageUrl,description,price]);

   useEffect(()=>{
       navigation.setParams({submit:submitHandler});
   },[submitHandler]);
```

but once the submithandler is executed and dispatching the action ends,when the screen re-renders then the fetching data from redux not works!

```
    const editedProduct= useSelector(state => state.product.userProducts.find(prod => prod.id === prodId));
```

its giving this error -
[image]
but at first without dispatching action, this code works perfectly.
need to solve this,any suggestions????
my update reducer-

```
  case UPDATE_PRODUCT:
           const productIndex=state.userProducts.findIndex(prod => prod.id===action.pid);

           console.log(state.userProducts[productIndex].price);
           const updatedProduct= new Product(
            action.pid,
            state.userProducts[productIndex].ownerId,
            action.productData.title,
            action.productData.imageUrl,
            action.productData.description,
            state.userProducts[productIndex].price
           );
         const updatedUserProducts= {...state.userProducts};
         updatedUserProducts[productIndex]=updatedProduct;
         const availableProductIndex=state.availableProducts.findIndex(prod => prod.id===action.pid);

         const updatedAvailableProducts= {...state.availableProducts};
         updatedAvailableProducts[availableProductIndex]=updatedProduct;

         return{
        ...state,
        userProducts:updatedUserProducts,
        availableProducts:updatedAvailableProducts
         };
```

Comment: Can you post the reducer?

Comment: editedProduct= useSelector(state => state.product && state.product.userProducts.find(prod => prod.id === prodId));

Comment: reducer works perfectly, the error is showing i that code only , because dispatching actions works

Comment: @Jean i posted the reducer

Comment: Checking the reducer, the updatedUserProducts is returning an object, and I believe that is why the find function does not work, can you do const updatedUserProducts= [...state.userProducts];

Comment: @Jean well thank you sir, thats works...thank you thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like another validation should be required:

```js
const editedProduct= useSelector(state => state.product.userProducts.find(prod => prod.id === prodId));

to

const editedProduct= useSelector(({product}) => product && product.userProducts && product.userProducts.find(prod => prod.id === prodId));
```

in order to be sure that `userProducts` is at least there before find.

Comment: same error is showing , now its showing 'product.userProducts.find isnot a function'

Comment: So is not setup yet when you are trying to reach it. Check how is that function initialized

Answer (score 0):

I think your `navigation.getParam('productId')` returns `String` instead of `Number`.
Thats why `userProducts.find(product => product.id === productId)` is undefined.

Try `Number(productId)`.